# Multiple Socket Connection in Android Multithreading Program

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm trying to connect multiple clients to a server using sockets and threads.  That is, every time a client connects to the port in the server, the server program creates a new thread and handles the connection on it's own thread.  Currently, I'm having a problem where it's connecting the same client twice.  Does anyone know how to prevent this problem?  Here's my code.

This is my code for the server connection:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ServerConnect {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
            InterruptedException {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        // boolean listening = true;

        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(20001);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());

            System.exit(-1);
        }
        int players = 6;
        ServerHello[] cArray = new ServerHello[players];
        Thread[] threadPool = new Thread[players];

        for (int i = 0; i < players; i++) {
            System.out.println("Connection number " + (i + 1)
                    + " waiting for client on port 20001.");
            Socket clientServer = serverSocket.accept();
            cArray[i] = new ServerHello(clientServer);
            threadPool[i] = new Thread(cArray[i]);
            threadPool[i].start();

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < players; i++)
            threadPool[i].join();



           //My Code


            for (int i = 0; i < players; i++) {
            cArray[i].closeConnect();
        }
        serverSocket.close();
```

I've tested the client side connection already and know it works.  For some reason though, the server keeps connecting the same client in sets of two.

Comment: It would have been nice to see the actual output from the println calls, also more such calls, also what you have found out during your own debugging, plus the thread code, plus the missing 'ServerHello' class.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can prevent it from happening is that each client should have a unique id. And then the server will accept a connection from a client, the client will send it's id to the server, the server will check that that same id is not connected already an only then create a new thread to handle it, otherwise you can drop the client connection